# sum of two columns assigned to a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

hi im trying to get the total of two columns stored to a name then get a condition but i having error on the 'Rebound' name on line 3

the offreb and defreb has a integer type and some values are stored as 0 (zero)

```
SELECT team, CONCAT(firstname,' ',lastname) AS name, SUM(offreb + defreb) AS Rebounds
FROM boxscore
WHERE round = 'Finals' AND game = 7 AND Rebounds > 0
ORDER BY team, Rebounds;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to filter by column in the WHERE clause which is not yet calculated when the WHERE clause is executed. You can use a sub-query or having.

It should be something like this:

```
SELECT team, CONCAT(firstname,' ',lastname) AS name, SUM(offreb + defreb) AS Rebounds
FROM boxscore
WHERE round = 'Finals' AND game = 7
GROUP BY team, CONCAT(firstname,' ',lastname)
HAVING SUM(offreb + defreb) > 0
ORDER BY team, Rebounds;
```

Comment: thanks it works!

just curious is the order of execution like this? -->
1. HAVING
2. GROUP BY
3. WHERE
4. FROM
5. SELECT
6. ORDER BY

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/a-look-into-sqls-order-of-execution-d0b81e361c66

Answer (score 1):

Here using `HAVING` clause solves your issue.

> If a table has been grouped using `GROUP BY`, but only certain groups
> are of interest, the HAVING clause can be used, much like a WHERE
> clause, to eliminate groups from the result.
> [Official postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUP)

```
SELECT
  team,
  CONCAT(firstname,' ',lastname) AS name,
  SUM(offreb + defreb) AS "Rebounds"
FROM 
  boxscore
WHERE
  round = 'Finals' AND game = 7
GROUP BY
  team,
  CONCAT(firstname,' ',lastname)
HAVING
  SUM(offreb + defreb) > 0
ORDER BY
  team, "Rebounds";
```

Note that you cannot use column alias in WHERE and GROUP BY clause, but can be used in ORDER BY clause and wrap double quotes to preserve case-sensitivity.